# Amazon Web Services: Managing Public DNS and Elastic IP Content Duplications with mod_rewrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite

I'm currently addressing content duplication issues of my AWS website for SEO purposes. More specifically I am trying to implement re-write rules for the duplicate addresses:

- Public DNS (ec2-my.ip.address.compute-1.amazonaws.com/anywebpage)
- Elastic IP (my.ip.address/anywebpage)

to my main domain http://mydomain.com/anywebpage

I have applied the following fix so far which only seems to rewrite/301 the homepage:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} my.ip.address.compute-1.amazonaws.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What it doesn't seem to do is apply the re-write rule for any webpage I visit under the duplicate address. For example, if I visit my.ip.address.blabla.com/mywebpage , I should be redirected to http://www.mydomain.com/mywebpage

Am I missing some key syntax here?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'm doing it, which works well for me.

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your regex might actually redirect to an extra / but appears that it should work otherwise.

You might try to turn on rewrite logging and use it to debug.  I find it very helpful at times.

```
  RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log
  RewriteLogLevel 4
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel for more info.